# Is Fermat's number composite for all $n>4$?

Tags: number-theory

Does there exist any proof that the number $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$ is composite for every $n>4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not proven, nor is the statement regarded to be true or false. As of this year, it is known that $F_n$ is composite for $5 \leq n \leq 32$.